# Import MySQL 5.6 Database in ProgramData dir to MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

When I was installing MySQL 5.6 if, there was a option to choose your MySQL database dir (I guess). I chose that option and set it to `D:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`. I was hoping that there would be the same on MySQL 5.7 installation but there is not. 
So, how to import the MySQL 5.6 database to 5.7?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. Best one is to always have a full dump of the database in case you need to regenerate from zero.
Other way is to allow mysql installer to do the upgrade. If the installer fails to take the previous datadir, you can manually specify it modifying the my.ini config file.
Search for an entry, which should look like this:

```
# Path to the database root
datadir=D:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/Data
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: (option 3): Is it ok for MySQL 5.7 to read the databases from 5.6 version?

Comment: As long as there is no major upgrade on the version it should be fine. But to be sure it's recommended to dump and regenerate from that.